# How to set document _id and _source with logstash and elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a file where each line is a JSON string like so:

```
{"_id":171962,"doc":{"account_id":53,"email":"user@gmail.com"}}
```

And the following logstash config:

```
input {
  s3 {
    codec => json_lines
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    doc_as_upsert => true
    action => "update"
    document_id => "%{[_id]}"
  }
  stdout { 
    codec => json_lines 
  }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters.
```

What I really want is to set the document id from `_id` and just set everything under `doc` property in the JSON as the document.

What configuration am I missing that will enable me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this.

```
 document_id => "%{_id}"
```

Also, you may want to use upsert instead of update if this is not really always update.